# Can I add a class to a erb variable interpolation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list item with a `link_to` inside and a name of `"Open"` and a interpolated variable called `@open` which is a count of open comments . I am wanting to put the data/number only that I get from the `@open` variable inside a bootstrap badge using `class="badge badge-pill badge-primary"`.

This is my line of code that I am trying to work on.

```
<li id="open" class="nav-item <%= 'active' if params[:q][:status_eq] == "open" %>">
  <%= link_to "Open #{@open}", comments_path(q: {status_eq: "open"}), class: 'nav-link' %>
</li>
```

I have tried to change the class on the erb from `nav-link` to `badge badge-pill badge-primary` but it puts the word `"open"` inside the badge.

I tried strange forms of interpolation and adding `class=""` or `class:` or `class=>` to the variable directly like `"Open #{@open class: "badge badge-pill badge-primary"}"` with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `@open` count to be wrapped in the Bootstrap badge and display `Open` as text only.

You can use [link_to](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) as a block and break out the HTML inside the link.

```html
<li id="open" class="nav-item <%= 'active' if params[:q][:status_eq] == "open" %>">
    <%= link_to comments_path(q: {status_eq: "open"}), class: 'nav-link' do %>
        Open <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary"><%= @open %></span>
    <% end %>
</li>
```